# auto foo(...) ->decltype(this) Is there some workaround?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have next class and try to declare  member function which will return pointer to a that type but next code

```
template<class Key, int b> class b_plus_tree_inner_node {
  auto split() -> decltype(this) {}
};
```

gives me such error

> invalid use of ‘this’ at top level

can i do it in another way, i now about existence of typedef, but may be its possible with decltype?

EDITED:

i want to accomplish this:

```
b_plus_tree_inner_node<Key, b>* split() {...}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: If you want a **member function** why do you declare it outside the class?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes , typo))

Comment: I think that "this" is not in scope until the function's opening brace, hence can't be part of the decltype.  Since "this" is a pseudo-parameter, it sounds like an oversight to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a **member** function declare it inside the class:

```
template<class Key, int b> class b_plus_tree_inner_node {
   b_plus_tree_inner_node* split(){}
   // also valid:
   //b_plus_tree_inner_node<Key, b>* split(){}
};
```

If you want a **non-member** function, make it a template:

```
template<class Key, int b>
b_plus_tree_inner_node<Key, b>* split(){}
```

The standard does allow you to write `auto split() -> decltype(this) {}` but GCC 4.6 doesn't support it yet (the trunk of GCC 4.7 does).

Comment: But the problem remains. See my 'answer'.

Comment: "You can only use this on the body of member functions." - this is not true. "this" can be used in a trailing return type within "decltype" too. That was set in stone in madrid, so his GCC does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
template<class Key, int b> 
class b_plus_tree_inner_node 
{        
     b_plus_tree_inner_node<Key, b> split() 
     { 
          return /*...*/;
     }
};
```

Comment: No need for the template arguments thanks to injected class names.

Comment: **injected class names** Interesting, i havent know about this. I want to vote up for it. Thanks.